# Boot locking mchanism

Tags: audi, security, trunk

Car boot won't shut tight won't click shut.removed top section and released spring which was stuck goes down but won't click tight.Audi 80 2.0. 92

Comment: Which body style? (Coupe, Avant, or Saloon)

Comment: It is a saloon. 20e.Played around with the top section ,closed but won't click tight to hook on power section.Thanks.